# Is there a pip environment variable that can used for extra parameters?

Tags: python, pip

I want to control the `--upgrade` behaviour of pip from outside the build scripts and I wondering if there is a `PIP_...` variable that I can configure that will be used by PIP by default, without having me to add it to each command line.

The documentation says something about [`PIP_` environment variables](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables) but fails to mention a list of them.

Comment: You can create the `PIP_...` environment variables on a per-user basis! So, there is no list because you decide what the `PIP_...` env variables are. If you're using Linux, then all you have to do is add an environment variable to the config file found here: `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`. So, for you're particular option, `--upgrade`, all you have to do is add a line under the command you're interested in (i.e., `[install]`) or if you want it to apply whenever you call upgrade, under `[global]`. That line would look a little like: `upgrade = specify-your-option-choice-here`.

Comment: Are you still having trouble on this topic? If so, please further clarify what your problem is. If you've found a solution to your problem, I would recommend that you compile a quick answer of your own and accept it so that this question will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**:

*EDIT*: Create a requirement specifier file that contains all of the packages you would like to upgrade, then include both the requirement specifier text file and the upgrade behavior your desire into your configuration file. Now you can upgrade any number of packages and any particular version of those packages with a simple command, `pip install`.

While I can't think of a one-line solution to this problem using environment variables, you can take advantage of environment variables to upgrade as many packages without using the `--upgrade` option of every installation command, shown below.

1. To control the upgrade behavior, update your pip environment variable: `export PIP_UPGRADE=True`.
2. To specify the package to upgrade, run the installation command you are used to: `pip install specifiedPackage`.

There is no comprehensive list of `pip` environment variables because they are something that is added for custom by the user / group of users. You can control the behavior of the `--upgrade` option for all `pip` commands, or just particular ones (like `pip install`), through your `pip` configuration file.

**Long Answer**:

**EDIT:** *Using Requirement Specifier Files*: You can create simple requirement specifier text files to specify packages you'd like to install. In fact, you can even specify particular versions of those packages within these files (if you prefer to install an older version or wish to avoid a particular version). A requirements file, `myRequirements.txt`, would look like this (mainly copied from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file)):

```
#
####### myRequirements.txt #######
#
###### Requirements without Version Specifiers ######
nose
nose-cov
beautifulsoup4
#
###### Requirements with Version Specifiers ######
#   See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers
docopt == 0.6.1             # Version Matching. Must be version 0.6.1
keyring >= 4.1.1            # Minimum version 4.1.1
coverage != 3.5             # Version Exclusion. Anything except version 3.5
Mopidy-Dirble ~= 1.1        # Compatible release. Same as >= 1.1, == 1.*
#
###### Refer to other requirements files ######
-r myOtherRequirements.txt
#
#
###### A particular file ######
./downloads/numpy-1.9.2-cp34-none-win32.whl
http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev1820+49a8884-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
#
###### Additional Requirements without Version Specifiers ######
#   Same as 1st section, just here to show that you can put things in any order.
anotherPackage
yetAnotherPackage
#
```

*Finding your configuration file*: All `pip` command line options and environment variables are set in a configuration file. Depending on what OS you installed `pip` on, the path to the configuration file will change... find yours in the same documentation, [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file).

*Editing your configuration file*: The organization is pretty simple. If you want the command line option change you're going to make to affect all `pip` commands, then you put it under a `[global]` statement. Otherwise, if you want it to only affect a single command (i.e., `pip install`) then you put it under a `[command-here]` statement (i.e., `[install]`). So, in summary it would look something like this:

```
[install]
upgrade = True
requirement = /path/to/myRequirements.txt
```

*Using the command line*: Now that you've overwrote the utility of the `pip install` command and you've specified your requirements specifier file containing all the packages you'd like to upgrade (and the version that you'd like to upgrade to -- if desired), you can simply call `pip install`, and you'll get the same effect as when you called `pip install --upgrade -r myRequirements.txt` before overwriting the behavior of the `--upgrade` and `-r` options.

**Note on `pip` environment variables**: I think you just read the documentation in the wrong order. You only use the environment variables AFTER you've added/changed something in the configuration file. Just using the example I gave above, you'd run the command `export PIP_UPGRADE=True` and then `pip install somePackage`. The two commands I just wrote out would have the same effect as the command `pip install --upgrade somePackage`. You only need to use environment variables when you want to change the behavior of the `--upgrade` option from whatever you set it to be in the configuration file!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it explains very well how pip env variables, config options and command line arguments work. Still, there os only one thing that I do not understand: the --upgrade option does NOT take parameters, you are supposed to use PIP_UPGRADE=True to enable upgrade mode, but the arguments / packages cannot be specified using env variables or inside config files. That's my impression.

Comment: I do apologize, my answer was flat out wrong. I am going to test some possibilities to see if there is a way to specify the package to be installed from the config file. For now, I have updated my answer to reflect correctly how you would take advantage of the `PIP_UPGRADE` environment variable to upgrade several packages without using having to include the `--upgrade` option.

Comment: It's not environment variables, but `pip` does have [requirement specifier files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file) that you can create to specify packages to install (and even specify which versions of those packages you want to install, if you prefer to install an older version). Once you create a requirements file, `myRequirements.txt`, you can install all the packages referenced in that file by `pip install -r myRequirements.txt`. Now, you can add under the `[install]` header a line such as `requirement = myRequirements.txt`.